# How to stop buttons wrapping to new line outside input-group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="col-xxs-12">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon-location-arrow"></i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></button>
</div>
```

This produces a form input with a button group attached on the end. It then renders a third, separate button: http://bootply.com/79114

Question: What's the cleanest way to stop this third button wrapping onto a new line? I want the input group (text input and two buttons) to display as they are and take 100% of the remaining width, but to have this third button on the same line. `Float:right.`

**EDIT** for the avoidance of doubt, I'd like the third button to be styled separately, outside of the `input-group`

Answer (score -1):

add this to third button

```
<div style="display:table-cell;width:1%">   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="-1"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></button></div>
```

[Demo](http://bootply.com/79128)

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem: I don't want this to be part of the input group. I want a third, standalone button on the same row.

Comment: Downvoting, not enough explanation given.  You need to provide at least a summary of the link provided.

Comment: Please read the guidelines on how to provide a complete answer ;)